# Объединить таблицы с новой индексацией

Tags: python, pandas

Есть два фрейма данных:

```
              x       1       2       3       4
   y    level_3             
   0    Close   1.32120 1.32724 1.31690 1.30860
        High    1.32176 1.32951 1.32903 1.31783
         Low    1.31650 1.32101 1.31461 1.30704
        Open    1.31908 1.32137 1.32702 1.31689
```

и

```
              x       1       2       3       4
   y    level_3             
   0    Close   1.32724 1.31690 1.30860 1.29995
        High    1.32951 1.32903 1.31783 1.31029
         Low    1.32101 1.31461 1.30704 1.29804
        Open    1.32137 1.32702 1.31689 1.30866
```

Когда я пытаюсь объединять `pd.concat` или `df.append` у меня объединяется всё в один индекс:

```
          x       1       2       3       4
y   level_3             
0   Close   1.32120 1.32724 1.31690 1.30860
     High   1.32176 1.32951 1.32903 1.31783
      Low   1.31650 1.32101 1.31461 1.30704
     Open   1.31908 1.32137 1.32702 1.31689
    Close   1.32724 1.31690 1.30860 1.29995
     High   1.32951 1.32903 1.31783 1.31029
      Low   1.32101 1.31461 1.30704 1.29804
     Open   1.32137 1.32702 1.31689 1.30866
```

Мне же нужно объединить их и получить разные значения `y`  для разных фреймов:

```
          x       1       2       3       4
y   level_3             
0   Close   1.32120 1.32724 1.31690 1.30860
     High   1.32176 1.32951 1.32903 1.31783
      Low   1.31650 1.32101 1.31461 1.30704
     Open   1.31908 1.32137 1.32702 1.31689
1   Close   1.32724 1.31690 1.30860 1.29995
     High   1.32951 1.32903 1.31783 1.31029
      Low   1.32101 1.31461 1.30704 1.29804
     Open   1.32137 1.32702 1.31689 1.30866
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: воспроизводимые примеры исходных данных в вопрос добавьте.

Comment: и по какому алгоритму должны меняться исходные значения `y` ?

Comment: @MaxU я подозреваю, что товарищу просто нужен мультииндекс, но опять же, гадать не будем

Comment: @strawdog, у товарища уже мультииндекс со столбцами “y” и “level_3”. Вот как раз о первом столбце мультииндекса я и спрашивал

Comment: @strawdog воспроизводимые примеры это что?

Comment: @MaxU алгоритм простой - добавляется фрейм со следующим по порядку числом

Comment: Ну вот хочу я вам помочь, у меня есть какие-то решение, мне нужно его проверить на вашем датасете. где я этот датасет возьму? или вам решение нужно "в сферическом вакууме"?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-p_MmIDyJbiysaeKnu5pB3Gtd1Z2IZjC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uRg1hdZFh4hVz430HBIsFdE3RBNHbcB1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: по этим ссылкам